# Slow UART communication between Raspberry Pi Zero and 4B using pyserial

Tags: serial, uart, communication, data-transfer

I'm testing serial communication between two Pi's (Zero -> Pi 4) with Python pyserial library. I am using Zero as camera with preprocessing and sending preprocessed data to Pi 4 via UART (/dev/ttyS0). Camera is working properly at 37FPS (27ms) and sending data (two float values - 8 bytes) to Pi 4 only on request. Pi 4 receive all 8 bytes and converts them into two floats successfully. BUT reading data on Pi 4 takes approx. 75ms. I found out that function pyserial.Serial.read(bytes) processes those 75ms. I also tried changing baudrate to different values (115200 and 250000) but with no effect. Same result was when I changed Pi 4 to Pi 3B+.

What might be the cause of slow reading from serial buffer using pyserial library?

Raspberry Pi Zero code:

```
with Serial('/dev/ttyS0', 250000) as ser:
    for frame in camera.capture_continuous(stream, format="yuv", use_video_port=True):
        start = time()
        ser.read(1)
        regions = self.__Regions(frame, self.__channel, self.__threshold, self.__disk)
        if (regions): coordinates = self.__Coordinates(regions)
        else: coordinates = [-1.0, -1.0]
        for value in coordinates: ser.write(pack('f', value))
        stream.truncate(0)
        end = time()
        print(end - start) # prints out 0.027s which is 37FPS
```

Raspberry Pi 4B code:

```
with Serial('/dev/ttyS0', 250000) as ser:
    while True:
        ser.write(1)
        start = time()
        data = ser.read(8) # this takes 0.075s 
        end = time()
        print(list(unpack('ff', data)))
        print(end - start) # prints out 0.075s
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh boiii I FKN FOUND IT!!! After a week of thinking.

The **problem** is with this sh@tty **camera connection** on Raspberry Pi Zero, which is somehow **interventing to the TX and RX pins** on ttyS0 port (UART0). I tested sending 1 byte from Pi 4 to Zero **without camera connection** and **it worked perfectly** 0.38ms!!!

But now, I have to deal with this problem so that the camera will work quick without interventing the UART...